# not pulling json

Tags: jquery, json

can't seem to figure out what's going wrong, the query is pulling the results but not json. Do you see where I went wrong?

```
    runningRequest=true;
    request = $.getJSON('/db/contacts.php',{
    q:$q.val()
    },function(data){           
    showResults(data,$q.val());
    runningRequest=false;
    });
    function showResults(data, highlight){
    var resultHtml = '';
    $.each(data, function(i,item){
    resultHtml+='<div class="result">';
    resultHtml+='<h2><a href="#">'+item.firstname+'</a></h2>';
    resultHtml+='<p>'+item.lastname.replace(highlight, '<span class="highlight">'+highlight+'</span>')+'</p>';
    resultHtml+='<a href="#" class="readMore">Read more..</a>'
    resultHtml+='</div>';
    });

    $('div#results').html(resultHtml);
    }
```

Comment: It's more than likely an issue withe the JSON coming from your server. Either run something like fiddler or firebug and get the output and run that output through jslint.com to see your errors.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about your problem? What exactly do you mean by it is pulling the results but not json?

Comment: For something like this, Firebug is your friend.  In the console, when you look at the request for db/contacts.php, what do you get?  If you put in console.log(data) just before showresults(data,$q, val()) what do you get in Firebug?

Comment: What do you mean by pulling result but not json? Try looking at response in FireBug console.

Comment: The result I get from my search looks like this: [{"Name":"Chris","Last Name":"Jones"}] instead of pushing results to json. What is meant by "serving valid JSON"?

Comment: I still can't seem to get this to work...I've tried looking in Firebug and not seeing anything. I'm getting results, they are just not being pushed to JSON. Any help would be great!

Comment: I've updated my answer below, addressing the JSON being formatted as a JSONArray, not a pure object.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead of the `$.getJSON()`:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/db/contacts.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { 'q':$q.val() }, //$q = ?
  success: function(data){           
    showResults(data, $q.val());
    runningRequest=false;
  });
});
```

Edit to address the comment below:

I'm guessing that you're using `json_encode()` to create the JSON in php, so try to use the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`-flag too (to keep it from turning into a JSONArray):

```
<?php echo json_encode($contact_string, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); ?>
```

What happens when you try the above?

Comment: tried this and get the same. Results show like this [{"Name":"Chris","Last Name":"Jones"}] which is right, but it's not passing to JSON. Any suggestions?

Comment: Updated my original post to address your further issues.

Comment: Thanks, I get: Warning: json_encode() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given

Comment: Are you using PHP 5.2? It seems like the OPTIONS-parameter was added in 5.3.

Comment: also, shouldn't $contact_string be $request?

Comment: I don't know about the $contact_string; that depends on what you've called your variable that you want to JSON:ize! I just added it there as a placeholder.

Comment: this is driving me nuts and probably a simple fix...any other suggestions?

Comment: Well, are you able to upgrade php to 5.3? If so, you'll probably be able to resolve the problem just by doing so (and adding the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`). If not, we'll have to dig a bit deeper!

Comment: I'm not able to unfortunately. If I remove it, I get a result but it's still not calling the JSON it's showing the result this way still: [{"Name":"Chris","Last Name":"Jones"}]

Comment: meaning removed JSON_FORCE_OBJECT

Comment: Check out the top answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375204/jquery-not-parsing-json-properly